# Is there a shorter method than alloc and initWithFormat for creating a NSString from two different data types?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to return a NSString* that will be created from a unsigned char and another NSString. initWithFormat allows combining two different datatypes to a String, but is there a shorter way to create the String than using alloc and initWithFormat?

```
NSString *stringMagic()
{
    unsigned char foo = 0x42;
    NSString *bar;

    // ...
    // Magic happens here
    // ...

    bar = @"unicorns";

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d %@", foo, bar];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think is "not smart" about this?

Comment: this question isn't super clear as to what the goal is

Comment: It seems clear enough, and the answer is as simple as "No". But answers are limited to some minimum of amount of characters, so I can't post that.

Comment: Well, you could always use `stringWithFormat`.  And, of course, you can use several other NSString functions to format an int into decimal, concatenate two strings, etc.

Comment: Thanks, stringWithFormat was what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChrisGraf Then please mark Dima's answer as "Accepted"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", foo, bar]
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I've ever used initWithFormat.